# MS Access Using a nested select within a switch for my query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using a nested Select within my Switch query and cannot seem to find the error hoping someone can spot it for me.

```
SELECT tblTaxiInvoices.TaxiInvID, tblTaxiInvoices.TaxiInvNo, tblChitRegister.pkchitnumber, tblClientRegister.fkTMS_Number, tblFunds.fund, tblFundCentres.fundcentre, tblCostCentres.costcentre, tblGLAccounts.glaccount, tblClientRegister.IO_id,     tblClientRegister.WBS_id, tblClientRegister.commit_code, tblChitRegister.faceamount, tblChitRegister.adminfee

, [faceamount]*0.884956 AS facenetofGST

,Switch
 (
 (Select HSTFactor From tblProvincialTaxes where tblTaxiInvoices.TaxiInvDateClosed >= CreatedDate and PID = 6 and active = 'yes') as TestfacenetofGST, ( [faceamount]* TestfacenetofGST )  ,

 (Select HSTFactor From tblProvincialTaxes where tblTaxiInvoices.TaxiInvDateClosed <= CreatedDate and PID = 6 and active = 'No') as TestfacenetofGST, ( [faceamount]* TestfacenetofGST ),0
 ) as xxx

, [facenetofGST]+[adminfee] AS TtlToClient

, tblTaxiCos.taxico, tblTaxiCos.prov, tblTaxiInvoices.Closed, tblTaxiInvoices.TaxiInvDateClosed
, (Select HSTFactor From tblProvincialTaxes where tblTaxiInvoices.TaxiInvDateClosed > CreatedDate and PID = 6 and active = 'yes') as test

FROM (tblTaxiCos INNER JOIN tblTaxiInvoices ON tblTaxiCos.pktaxico_id = tblTaxiInvoices.TaxiCoID) INNER JOIN (tblGLAccounts INNER JOIN (tblFunds INNER JOIN (tblFundCentres INNER JOIN (tblCostCentres INNER JOIN (tblClientRegister INNER JOIN     tblChitRegister ON tblClientRegister.pkclient_id = tblChitRegister.fkclient_id) ON tblCostCentres.pkcostcentre_id = tblClientRegister.fkcostcentre_id) ON tblFundCentres.pkfundcentre_id = tblClientRegister.fkfundcentre_id) ON tblFunds.pkfund    _id =     tblClientRegister.fkfund_id) ON tblGLAccounts.pkglaccount_id = tblClientRegister.fkglaccount_id) ON tblTaxiInvoices.TaxiInvID = tblChitRegister.taxiinv_ID
WHERE (((tblTaxiCos.prov)="ON"))
```

Comment: Please post the error raised by running this query.

Comment: The query does not make much sense without an explanation of what you want to retrieve, together with sample date for all related tables and the expected output for them. The syntax is wrong inside the `Switch`. You cannot do `as TestfacenetofGST` in one of the expressions and then reference that in the next. But without knowing what output you expect, I don't see how we can help you.

Comment: I have reposted I had edited everything out for easier reading.

Comment: I also have the impression you could reduce the query to a bare minimum, with just one or two tables involved, enough to reproduce the problem. It does not help to throw 7 more tables in the query when they really do not contribute to the error.

Comment: So within the Switch statement I am trying to retrieve the tax rates from another table based upon the date of the invoice. As you can see just above the switch the factor is hard coded I have the rates in a table.

Comment: Missing operator in Query expression switch

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is probably multiple errors but here is one:

You are using `tblTaxiInvoices.TaxiInvDateClosed` in `WHERE` but `tblTaxiInvoices` is not in your `FROM`.